# redirect doesnt' apply with sinatra on localhost machine

Tags: ruby, redis, sinatra

```
get '/:shortcode' do
    @url = redis.get "links:#{params[:shortcode]}"
    if !@url.nil?
        redis.incr "clicks:#{params[:shortcode]}"
        redirect @url
    else
        redirect '/'
    end
end
```

This is the snippet, it gets key with the params and checks if its `nil?`. Its necessary to avoid that redis.incr creates random keys if they are not available.

The problem is that I get redirected to `/` all the time. Any idea?

```
[2014-01-10 18:37:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-01-10 18:37:50] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra/1.4.4 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2014-01-10 18:37:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=13862 port=4567
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 18:37:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1312 0.0038
localhost - - [10/Jan/2014:18:37:55 CET] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1312
http://localhost:4567/ -> /
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 18:37:55] "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0004
localhost - - [10/Jan/2014:18:37:55 CET] "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
http://localhost:4567/ -> /css/main.css
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 18:37:55] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0010
localhost - - [10/Jan/2014:18:37:55 CET] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0
- -> /favicon.ico
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 18:38:07] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1449 0.0022
localhost - - [10/Jan/2014:18:38:07 CET] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1449
http://localhost:4567/ -> /
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 18:38:14] "GET /br5z9 HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0010
localhost - - [10/Jan/2014:18:38:14 CET] "GET /br5z9 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
http://localhost:4567/ -> /br5z9
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 18:38:14] "GET /google.com HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0007
localhost - - [10/Jan/2014:18:38:14 CET] "GET /google.com HTTP/1.1" 302 0
http://localhost:4567/ -> /google.com
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 18:38:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1312 0.0024
localhost - - [10/Jan/2014:18:38:14 CET] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1312
http://localhost:4567/ -> /
```

Edit:
In this example I added `google.com` in the form which gets processed by

```
post '/' do
    if params[:url] and not params[:url].empty?
        @shortcode = random_string 5
        redis.multi do
            redis.set "links:#{@shortcode}", params[:url], :nx => true, :ex => 400
            redis.set "clicks:#{@shortcode}", "0", :nx => true, :ex => 400
        end
    end
    erb :index
end
```

The case of hardcoding an url:

Change `redirect @url` to `redirect 'google.com'` gives that.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 18:55:32] "GET /google.com HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0008
localhost - - [10/Jan/2014:18:55:32 CET] "GET /google.com HTTP/1.1" 302 0
http://localhost:4567/ -> /google.com
```

Comment: which is the sample containment of `@url`, can you hardcode a sample url to simulate correct redirect, and then show us your other routes.

Comment: what is in `@url` if I set a valid url there your code works fine for me

Comment: Ok, checked it further... if I use a link like ``google.com`` it doesnt work. If I use `http://google.com`` it works oO

Comment: the first thing isn't really a url, what show this `puts "url: #{@url}"` for not working links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redirect doesnst recognize `google.com` as a external link and tries to route to `http://localhost:4567/google.com`.

So the trick is to use `http://google.com`. I solved it with a rewrite of the submited string.

```
unless params[:url] =~ /[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/.*/
    params[:url] = "http://#{params[:url]}"
end
```